# python permutations algorithm based on recursion

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I try to implement permutation algorithm. It works well.

But my questions about recursion in this algorithm

Permutation function:

```
def permutations(word):
```

**how and why it continue to work after return statement?**

```
    if len(word) == 1:
        return [word]
```

**how it goes back if last perms == ['3'] how it back to ['23'] from ['3']?**

```
    perms = permutations(word[1:])
    char = word[0]
    result = []

    for perm in perms:
        for i in range(len(perm) + 1):
            result.append(perm[:i] + char + perm[i:])
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood. Recursion based on stack. That is why it continue to execute after return statement.